# How to add all selected elements into an array and iterate through it?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have the elements below

-- a. I want to add the 3 div block of parent_1 into an array.

-- b. Then loop through the array and add each div block (individually) into parent_2.

I want to do these with pure JavaScript. Is it possible?

Thank you.

```
<div class="parent_1">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>

<div class="parent_2">
   <!-- add here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `querySelectorAll` with selector `.parent_1 > div` to get all direct `div` inside `.parent_1` then use `forEach` and `cloneNode` to add them to `.parent_2`.

Demo:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.parent_1 > div');
var parent_2 = document.querySelector('.parent_2');
divs.forEach((div) => {
  parent_2.appendChild(div.cloneNode(true));
})
```

```html
<div class="parent_1">
   <div>
      <div></div>
   </div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>

<div class="parent_2">
   <!-- add here -->
</div>
```

Note that if you use `.parent_1 div` with the html above, you will get 4 `div` in `.parent_2`.

Comment: Thank you but is there a way to exclude anything inside the sub divs (I only need the 3 child divs)?

Comment: use `cloneNode()` instead of `cloneNode(true)` may solve that.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in following steps:

- First use `querySelectorAll()` to get all the `<div>` elements in `parent_1`
- Then select the `parent_2` using `querySelector()`
- Loop through the `div` using `forEach()`
- clone each `div` using `cloneNode()` and add it to `parent_2` using `appendChild()`

```js
let elms=  document.querySelectorAll('.parent_1 div');
let parent2 = document.querySelector('.parent_2');
elms.forEach(x => {
  parent2.appendChild(x.cloneNode(true));
})
```

```html
<div class="parent_1">
   <div>A</div>
   <div>B</div>
   <div>C</div>
</div>

<div class="parent_2">
   <!-- add here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Quick question: What if all the 3 child div containing sub divs inside them? So they will be appended into parent_2? If so, how can I exclude them?

Comment: NVM I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way using `querySelectorAll` and `cloneNode`

```js
(function() {
  let nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.parent_1 div');
  let dest = document.getElementById('parent_2');
  nodes.forEach(e => {
    let clone = e.cloneNode(true);
    dest.appendChild(clone);
  });
})();
```

```css
.parent_1 {
  background: red;
}

.parent_2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_1">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent_2" id="parent_2">
  <!-- add here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.parent_1').children().each(function() {
        $(this).appendTo('.parent_2');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: OP has asked for a JS solution *I want to do these with pure JavaScript. Is it possible?*